# Does anyone know what this vintage aluminum container was called and used for?

Tags: alcohol, distribution

[image]Hello. I found this aluminum container in a  recycling bin.
It is about 8 inches tall and 5 inches wide at the bottom.

Someone told me its called a growler and was used to take home beer from a bar,
but I don't know if that's accurate.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it’s for alcohol? Looks like a milk container to me.

Comment: For instance https://www.ebay.com/itm/100-Yr-Old-Arden-SLC-Vintage-Milk-Can-Jug-Rare/192991228550?hash=item2cef2c7286:g:YcgAAOSwoyhdKqLJ

Comment: Are you sure it's aluminum?  It looks a little rusty just under the lid (but perhaps it's only dirt).

Comment: Definitely aluminum due to the low weight, but the main handle systems to be steel. Aluminum does tarnish, but it looks more whiteish.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is a vintage milk jug if you picture search on Google "[vintage aluminum milk jug](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rls=en&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=vintage%20aluminum%20milk%20jug&client=safari&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj507Gn4p7uAhWVcc0KHbweD68QjJkEegQIAhAB)" you'll get a lot of similar hits. Every growler I've seen has been glass although I'm no expert.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head, Eric. It does indeed look like a milk jug. Absoulutely no odor or residue in it though.

Comment: Well, yours is a good looking one and I think they have some value on eBay.

Comment: Old milk cans were much larger though, up to 25 gallons. Newer cans were smaller, but still at least 5 or 10 gallons. See [How to Date Old Milk Cans | LoveToKnow](https://antiques.lovetoknow.com/antique-price-guides/how-date-old-milk-cans#:~:text=Older%20milk%20cans%20from%20the,the%2019th%20or%2020th%20centuries.).  Growlers are typically 64 fluid ounces, which is about the size of the pictured can.

Comment: @RayButterworth I’m not an expert, but I think milk jugs come in various sizes. Never seen a growler look anything like what the OP pictured. Not in a Google image search either.

Comment: @RayButterworth Also, I doubt you’d design a growler with a wide lid since it would make containing the pressure much harder.

Comment: "In the late 1800s, fresh beer was carried from the local pub to home by a small, galvanized pail. The term “growler” is rumored to come about when the beer sloshed around the pail; it created a rumbling sound as the CO2 escaped through the lid." — [Growler History](http://growler-station.com/about/history). In particular see the first photo from the 1800s. Unlike modern growlers, they were intended for transporting draft home to have with dinner, not for storage.

Comment: To me it looks like a sealed lid. A sealed lid of that diameter times the pressure of beer could be dangerous. As I said, I’m just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

**Does anyone know what this vintage aluminum container was called and used for?**

Personally, I believe it to be an old **milk jug**!

Having milked cows back in the days gone by, I am sure this is a milk jug.

This [eBay site](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/Vintage-Aluminum-Milk-Can-with-Lid-Made-in-USA/324452846098?hash=item4b8ae58a12:g:R9QAAOSwIlRgALZ8) demonstrates where I am going.